# SQL Server ORDER BY Not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
$query=mssql_query ('SELECT USER_INDEX_ID FROM T_o2jam_login');
echo "<table border =\"0\" style=\"color: gray;\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" CLASS='boldtable'><tr><th colspan=\"9\">Online Players</th></tr><tr><td>Level  </td> <td> Nick </td> </tr>";
if (mssql_num_rows($query)) {
      while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)) {
$q2 = mssql_query ("select * from t_o2jam_charinfo where USER_INDEX_ID=$row[USER_INDEX_ID] ORDER BY Level DESC");
$nt=mssql_fetch_array($q2);
echo "<tr><td>Lv. $nt[Level]  </td><td>  $nt[USER_NICKNAME] </td></tr>" ;
```

I am trying to sort online users by Level on Descending order. From 99 to Level 1. It displays the data but they are not sorted. What's the problem right there? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the order by in your first query. Your second query is within a loop, so it's going to first go by the order of the first one.

This really should be one query with a JOIN.

```
SELECT charinfo.*, FROM t_o2jam_charinfo charinfo 
INNER JOIN T_o2jam_login login 
ON charinfo.USER_INDEX_ID = login.USER_INDEX_ID
ORDER BY `Level` DESC
```

But since you never use any of the info from the "login" table, one wonders why it's even used at all.

Anyway, never run queries in loops.